# Concurrent initialization and copy of variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, condition-variable

I only have recently began studying concurrency in C++ and i am trying to make the following code display x and y as 1. Despite obtaining the correct result, it sometimes enters a deadlock and I cannot figure out why. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong or provide me with an alternative solution? Thanks in advance!

```
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int a = 0, b = 0;
mutex m1, m2;
condition_variable cond1, cond2;
void f1()
{   
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m1);
    a = 1; 
    cond2.wait(lock, []{ return b == 1; });
    cond1.notify_one();
    int x = b;
    cout << "x" << x << endl;

}

void f2()
{ 
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m2);
    b = 1;
    cond2.notify_one();
    cond1.wait(lock, [] { return a == 1; } );
    int y = a;
    cout << "y" << y << endl;

}

int main()
{
    thread t1(f1);
    thread t2(f2);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: f1 waits for f2 to signal cond2 but if f2 signals cond2 before f1 starts to wait you will have a dead lock.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have put the second thread to sleep for a few milliseconds to make sure i reach the waiting condition in f1.

Comment: That would not be a good solution. Imagine your example is more complex and execution time of f1 varies widely - you couldn't determine how long you need to sleep in f2 to not have a deadlock. Please tell us more what you are trying to achieve because it's hard to tell right now.

Comment: Just a reminder, when you cout, you will have to lock the stream. Otherwise you'll have a nearly unreadable output...